# Hyperledger Fabric 1.1 TLS GRPC issue

Tags: docker, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2, grpc

I am working on integrating a Middleware client that will connect to a Hyperledger Fabric network to call chaincode on my network. We have built a network which has TLS enabled, and it is similar to the [Fabric CA Sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/fabric-ca) here. We have installed and instantiated our chaincode on all of the peers successfully on the server (right now all of the peers are running as docker images on the server). I am able to call chaincode inside of the containers on the docker network. I have written the code which will call the channel to make transactions, and we tested on a separate network without TLS successfully. Now we are trying to add TLS functionality. In order to do this, I took the certs from the server and added them to my local orderer properties before calling the channel. My Java code is throwing the following error:

```
04/06/18 13:41:37 L[E]C[org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel] Channel mychannel sendDeliver failed on orderer orderer1. Reason: UNAVAILABLE: Channel closed while performing protocol negotiation
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel sendDeliver failed on orderer orderer1. Reason: UNAVAILABLE: Channel closed while performing protocol negotiation
```

Relevant Java Code for Orderer/Peer setup:

```
 peerProperties.setProperty("pemFile", "C:/fabriccerts/data/Peer1-ca-chain.pem");
 peerProperties.put("clientCertBytes", Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\fabriccerts\\data\\tls\\peer1-cli-client.crt")));
 final String keyString = getPEMStringFromPrivateKey(loadPrivateKey("C:\\fabriccerts\\data\\tls\\peer1-cli-client.key"));
 peerProperties.put("clientKeyBytes",keyString.getBytes(UTF_8));
 peerProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); //testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!    
 peerProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", peerName);
 peerProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
 peerProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
 peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
 channel.addPeer(client.newPeer(peerName, peerGRPCURL,peerProperties));
 ...
 static String getPEMStringFromPrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) throws IOException {
    StringWriter pemStrWriter = new StringWriter();
    PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(pemStrWriter);

    pemWriter.writeObject(privateKey);

    pemWriter.close();

    return pemStrWriter.toString();
 }

private PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String stringKey) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PrivateKey key = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(stringKey);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean inKey = false;
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            if (!inKey) {
                if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                    inKey = true;
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                if (line.startsWith("-----END ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                    inKey = false;
                    break;
                }
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
        //
        byte[] encoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(builder.toString());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        try {
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");
            key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return key;
}
```

On the orderer docker image, i see this error:

```
2018-04-06 17:41:37.300 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU b70 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "148.132.123.187:59618": remote error: tls: internal error
```

Also on the orderer i have set the logging environment variable to

```
- CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=DEBUG
```

And this is the only log i see being generated. Is there any way i can get more insight into why the handshake is failing? Also, can the problem be that my pemFile is not valid on my machine, even though its valid on the server?

Edit: I am able to connect to the peer using the following command from another server:

```
openssl s_client -connect myhost.com:51721 -CAfile 
$DATADIR/Peer1-ca-chain.pem -cert $DATADIR/tls/peer1-cli-client.crt -key 
$DATADIR/tls/peer1-cli-client.key
```

But now when i use these same credentials in my request I am getting the following error, I updated my properties code above as i had some modifications:

```
grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "148.132.34.163:55159": tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "rca-Peer1-admin")
```

Comment: can you do a: "tcpdump -w out.log" to the interface and attach the tcpdump log so i can take a look at it?

Comment: Ok put the file here https://ufile.io/albre

Comment: i don't see any TLS handshake at all

Comment: @yacovm It **is** TLS 1.2 ; right clic on any packet and Apply Decode As SSL

Comment: Does the CN or one of the SANs in the orderer's TLS certificate match the hostname you are using in your client?   That is, does the host portion of ordererGRPCURL match the actual CN/SAN in the orderer's TLS server cert?

Comment: oh @EugèneAdell i picked the wrong stream... so you're trying to connect to "orderer1-supplychain"  ?

Comment: @GariSingh so the way the network is built now, I have exposed the docker image port 7050 for the orderer, but I am running it on a server and calling that server through its host name. I am not sure how to tell if the CN/SAN on the orderers TLS cert has that hostname on it or not. The network does run inside of one server however, and from inside the docker containers I am able to call the chaincode successfully. If it helps, it's similar to the Fabric CA example from fabric-samples.

Comment: @yacovm Yes that's the orderer i am trying to connect to

Comment: Can you try running  "openssl s_client -showcerts -connect orderer1-supplychain:7050" and add the response to the issue above?

Comment: @GariSingh ok I added the response above

Comment: @GariSingh Actually I realized i was doing this command the wrong way, I made some updates above, please let me know if its of any help. Thanks!